# plugin fail to connect Coverity server

Tags: coverity

coverity plugin verison:1.9.2
system configuration:
Coverity static Analysis location: /opt/coverity/x86_64/8.7.1/
coverity port 8443
Coverity web services were not detected. Connection attempt responded with -1, check Coverity Connect version (minimum supported version is 7.7.0).

if port is changed to 8080, connection is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a broken SSL cert.  Coverity needs to use a cert signed by an authority recognized by your system certs.  Checkout [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) to a free cert and then read the manual on how to install it in Coverity Connect.